# GNU make: make ignores some exported variables?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given this Makefile:

```
ifndef DEIS_NUM_INSTANCES
    DEIS_NUM_INSTANCES=3
endif

ifndef DEIS_HOSTS
    DEIS_HOSTS = $(shell seq -f "172.17.8.%g" -s " " 100 1 `expr $(DEIS_NUM_INSTANCES) + 99` )
endif

DUMMY:
    for host in $(DEIS_HOSTS); do echo $$host; done
```

No matter what I export `DEIS_HOSTS` to, the `ifndef DEIS_HOSTS` is always evaluated:

```
bash-3.2$ export DEIS_HOSTS="1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5"
bash-3.2$ make
for host in 172.17.8.100 172.17.8.101 172.17.8.102 ; do echo $host; done
172.17.8.100
172.17.8.101
172.17.8.102
```

However, passing the variables right to `make` seems to work:

```
bash-3.2$ DEIS_HOSTS="1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5" make
for host in 1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5; do echo $host; done
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
```

Can someone explain this behavior? It's quite confusing, especially considering `DEIS_NUM_INSTANCES` doesn't work that way:

```
bash-3.2$ export DEIS_NUM_INSTANCES=6
bash-3.2$ make
for host in 172.17.8.100 172.17.8.101 172.17.8.102 172.17.8.103 172.17.8.104 172.17.8.105 ; do echo $host; done
172.17.8.100
172.17.8.101
172.17.8.102
172.17.8.103
172.17.8.104
172.17.8.105
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check for typos. `VAR=val command` is equivalent to `(export VAR=val; command)`.

Comment: When I copy and paste your makefile and your commands it works here.

Comment: check by adding `?=` instead of `=` in `DEIS_HOSTS = $(shell seq -f "172.17.8.%g" -s " " 100 1 expr $(DEIS_NUM_INSTANCES) + 99 )`

Comment: make file working fine as it is. check the version

Comment: This is driving me nuts - I'm using this verbatim. Make version:
GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 0):

So, this is embarrassing. Coming back to this problem today, it works as intended. I have no idea what changed between yesterday and today... the Makefile is the same. Anyway, thanks everyone for confirming that I am indeed crazy!